# Does implementing lazy loading make sense for mobile apps?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, webview, hybrid-mobile-app

I'm new to Ionic and mobile development in general and I've been wondering whether lazy loading makes sense for mobile apps, since the app is already fully installed on a mobile device.

It makes sense to implement lazy loading for a web app since it can gradually load required code bundles (components, pages,...), but what about mobile apps? Does it make sense? Or am I missing/misunderstanding something here?

Comment: yes lazy loading is help to reduce startup load time and so performance will definitely improve. if your application big then performance will much better.

Comment: Short answer, yes.

Comment: @wentjun yes right